# Ionic and phonegap barcode scanner app crash on android

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4, phonegap-plugins

My ionic app uses:

```
"@ionic-native/barcode-scanner": "^5.19.1",
"phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "^8.1.0",
```

Android app crashes right away when i call barcode.scan funcion. I am doing everything like on the very basic example: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner

Note: I am testing this on android7 version at the moment. The phone is not very new but still not very old neither.
It crashes right after accepting **camera permissions.**

There is no err message in catch block or anything, app just crashes.
Has anyone experienced this or can help me investigate more logs ?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue, basicly it was missing com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN from AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Not sure why the plugin installation did not added anything nor it was described in github, but It was requiring activity for the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

AndroidManifest.xml:12:9-21:20 Error:
android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

Comment: Please can you format a little ?

Comment: Ugly formatting